# how to pass data between templates meteor js

Tags: mongodb, meteor, flow-router

i'm working with Meteor js and i'm trying to pass data from a template to another and this is my code :

**BuildingsAction.js**

```
  Template.BuildingsAction.viewmodel({
     showExhibitions() {

        FlowRouter.go("/exhibitions");

    },})
```

Actually i would like to pass an _id from BuildingsAction to exhibitions

```
   Template.exhibitions.viewmodel({
    onCreated: function () {
        this.idItemParent(BuildingsAction_id)// here i whoud like to get the id 
        })}
```

Comment: Are you calling from template inside a template ?

Comment: i have tow templates exhibitions is the one wich contain the details of the first template so i need to find a link between the both.

Comment: i would like to set  this.idItemParent() to the value comming from the first template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways.

**1. Using session.**

```
`Session.set('idVar',YourId);`
```

Get Session Value:
    `Session.get('idVar');`

**2. You can send the id in URL**

`FlowRouter.go("/exhibitions",{},{id:YourID});`

Get queryparam Value:
    `FlowRouter.getQueryParam("id");`

Comment: well, then how can I get it in "exhibitions"

Comment: Update my answer Have a look

Comment: Use any one of on your exhibitions on created to get value.

Comment: Use method 2. Session variables should be used for storing data that will persist. The FlowRouter parameter example is exactly the use for which it was created.